# After upgrading to Windows 10 I have lost all my programs and documents

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

My computer just upgraded from Windows 7 to 10.

It happened overnight and I never got any option to preserve my files, it has kept a couple of programs but all of my documents, music and pictures have gone.

If I restore to Windows 7 will I get them all back?

Or is there some where I can get them back whilst still keeping Windows 10?

The problem was someone in my house unplugged my hard disk so my external backup never completed prior to the upgrade commencing.

Comment: look in C:\ for a windows.old folder. It includes the old programs

Comment: Any chance you have a different user name now? Like, MAYBE Windows did migrate the documents, but as you're a different user now, you just don't see them?

Answer (score 2):

Go to C:\Windows.old

There should be a 'Users' folder. All your files should be in there. If you can't find it, turn on hidden folders and try again.